# Is it possible to use SVG or Canvas chart with a lot of data?

Tags: rgraph

I use Canvas to draw line (3500 lines),
My JSP/html has No response,
I can not click any other element(button, textbox...),
How should I draw 3500 lines?

```
var powerDataList = new Array();
var powerData = new Array();    
//powerDataList.length == 3500
for (var i = 0; i < powerDataList.length; i++) {
    //data length == 960; Example: data = [1,2,3,...,960];
    powerDataList[i] = data ；
}
var line = new RGraph.SVG.Line({
    id: 'chart-container',
    data:powerDataList,
    options: {
        linewidth: 1,
        colors: colors,
        xaxis: true,
        yaxis: false,
        yaxisMax:10,
        yaxisLabelsCount: 0,
        yaxisScale: false,
        xaxisLabels:label,
        xaxisTickmarks: false,
        //tooltips: tooltips,
        linewidth: 1,
        title: 'power',
        titleSize:10
        }
    }).draw();
```

Answer (score 0):

With that much data I would suggest canvas - it's faster. But with 3500 lines there's going to be lots of overlap so you might just end up seeing some big blocks of colour.